# PHP function getHeader()

Tags: php, mysql

Hey guys, Im building a fairly large website here, I am using quite a bit of php along with it, but what I was wondering, I have a header that does't change throughout the website, and I was wondering if I could create a function in some of my php code where all I would have to do is call like a function getHeader() and it will return the header. Now this header has some php in it also like a search bar and a username container... I was just wondering if this was possible on a fairly simple scale so I don't have to place the header code in each php file. which is fine but if I happen to make an update I have to update file which could take some time...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create a header file (e.g. header.php) and include it.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

You can either have the code directly in the header.php not in any functions, and it will run by default, or put it in a function and call it manually.

Comment: Okay thanks guys... I was thinking about trying that I just wanted to make for sure that it would work before I actually did it... I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

A simple include() at the top of every file is what you'll need http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use a function. That's what WordPress does. You could even put PHP inside them. You'd just have to keep in mind that the PHP inside your function is... well... inside a function. So you'd have to explicitly access global variables, etc.

Another option would be to put the header in its own, single file and just `include` that file, instead of calling a function. Whatever floats your boat.